# Config complex type for value object using NHibernate in C#

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I am new to DDD and NHibernate, when I try to config for table(using code-first) with NHibernate fluent.

In EntityFramework we can use ComplexTypeConfiguration to config for value object and using that config in many table, but I have no idea how NHibernate separate config for value object like EntityFramework.

```
internal class EmployeeConfiguration : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        Table("Employees");
        Id(emp => emp.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Component(emp => emp.FullName, name =>
        {
            name.Map(ele => ele.FirstName).Column("FirstName").Length(255).Not.Nullable();
            name.Map(ele => ele.LastName).Column("LastName").Length(255).Not.Nullable();
            name.Map(ele => ele.MiddleName).Column("MiddleName").Length(255).Nullable();
        });
    }

}
```

I googled for find out solutions, but nothing really helpful.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208413/mapping-a-liststring-to-a-delimited-string-with-fluent-nhibernate/4314175

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's not my problem ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my understanding, you need a reusable ComplextType configuration which can be implemented on various tables. So far so good, according to [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/nhibernate-for-entity-framework-developers-part-1-fluent-nhibernate) 
*"If you are mapping an entity you'd use ClassMap and if you are mapping a value object you'd use ComponentMap class"*. Hence, I built a solution based on it, perhaps it's not the right answer, but hopefully, this would help.

```
//Complex type class
public class Address
{
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Street { get; set; }
    public virtual string StateOrProvince { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
}

//Entity
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Salary { get; set; }
}

//ComplexTypeConfiguration
public class AddressMap : ComponentMap<Address>
{
   public AddressMap()
   {
       Map(c => c.City).Column("City").Length(255).Not.Nullable();
       Map(c => c.Country).Column("Country").Length(255);
       Map(c => c.StateOrProvince).Nullable();
       Map(c => c.Street).Nullable();
   }
}

//Mapping
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("Employees");

        Id(c => c.Id);
        Map(c => c.FullName);
        Map(c => c.Salary);
        Component(c => c.Address);
    }
}

//Connection string
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
            .ConnectionString(@"Server=.;Database=TestDB;Trusted_Connection=True;")
            .ShowSql())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true))
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        Console.WriteLine("Database Connected");
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}    

//Test script    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee()
        {
            Id = 1,
            FullName = "Nidust Ashen",
            Salary = 12345678,
            Address = new Address()
            {
                City = "test1",
                Street = "test2",
                Country = "test3",
                StateOrProvince = "test4",
            }
        };

        session.Save(employee);
        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Final result:**

[image]

[image: Result]